# Run logic on same date only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where my logic is comparing my column 0 (list of time) to a 24hour javascript clock, and returns a stoplight color scheme on the row depending on how close the times are.

The issue is when its 23:00(11pm) and there is a item in my time column that read "2:10am"(next day) my logic thinks its a late time, and does not recognize it's tomorrow's item. my color coding logic works but I only need this to execute if cell[0] date is equal to the system date(js clock).

```
    //date time object 
        var t = new Date();

    // loops through each row
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

        //configures the clock
        var hm = cells[0].innerText.split(":");
        t.setHours(hm[0], hm[1], 0, 0);
        var r = (t.getTime() - currentTime.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60;

        //logic  executed

             if (r <= 0.25 && cells[1].innerText == false)
                rows[i].className = "ewTableRowConditionalRed";

            else if (r > 0.25 & r <= 0.5 && cells[1].innerText == false)
                rows[i].className = "ewTableRowConditionalYellow";

            else if (r > 0.5 & r <= 2 && cells[1].innerText == false)
                rows[i].className = "ewTableRowConditionalGreen";

    }
```

Comment: You say that your your logic is executing? It seems to me like you should be getting an error doing this comparison `cells[i].innerText == false`. `innerTEXT` should be returning a string, which should not be comparable to the value `false`.

Comment: its a rapid prototype and the logic is working. I just need my logic not to execute on a column cell where the TimeStamp is reading tomorrow's time (ex 2am)

Comment: if you compare {string} to false you will get true ( unless it is a zero length string). http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how your time is represented. Could you make a fiddle? is the time in cell 0 a string representation of the current system time? does it have am or PM in it? Is there a date in that cell?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you first need to be comparing the date (not datetime) of the two things first. You can do this using the getYear(), getMonth(), getDate() methods.

```
var origDate = new Date(); //or the you're getting from the td
var roundedDate = new Date(origDate.getYear(), origDate.getMonth()+1, origDate,getDay());
```

Note that getMonth() return a number from 0 to 11.

If your code can potentially run in different timezones, best to convert to and compare UTC dates.